Есть ли смысл в подключении 2 роутера к 1 в качестве точки доступа для безопасности?
Ситуация: я хочу использовать один из пк для проверки сторонних приложений с учетом подключения к интернету.
Есть ли смысл в подключении 2 роутера в качестве точки доступа к основному? Или же достаточно использовать гостевую сеть без доступа в интранет?

достаточно использовать гостевую сеть без доступа в интранет - да
